# How to change the config file path.?

Tags: c#, config

I have two projects, let them be **Prj1** and **Prj2**. Both of them have their own config files. I am referring **Prj2** in **Prj1**.

In **Prj2** I am doing something with the config file. But the problem is, as I am referring **Prj2** in **Prj1**, when the execution comes to **Prj2** from **Prj1**, it is still referring to **Prj1**'s config file.

As a result I am getting configuration exception in my Prj2 Project.
I don't want to hard code the path of config file.

Anybody suggest me the right way to perform this.

Comment: Is prj2 a DLL or an executable project ?

Comment: hi @Fabjan Prj2 is DLL

Comment: what exactly are you trying to accomplish ? Please be more specific and provide some code

Comment: Hi @Fabjan, I need to maintain **Prj2** as a DLL and will refer that in 'n' number of projects. I can update the **Prj2** config file at anytime. When the execution comes to **Prj2** then my code should refer to executing assembly (i.e., Prj2) config file and when execution completed then it should refer back to the calling assembly config file.

Answer (score 0):

When I have faced the problem like the same I have used this

```
string path = 
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\SomeName" ;
```

This will point to

```
C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Roaming\
```

Which will always be going to have same path still not hard-coded

Answer (score 0):

This sort of depends on how you look at the problem. If **Proj1** is your main project, with the main / overall responsibility for the tasks to carry out, then it seems to make sense to use config settings from that project.

As such, your quickest solution would probably be to simply duplicate the config values, and add them to the settings for **Proj1**.

Comment: Hi @Kjartan, your suggestion is correct i.e., we can copy the config file values to Proj1 but my intention is to keep only one config file and that should be referred by other Projects.